# ASP.Net MVC in subfolder 403 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I managed to run an MVC application inside a regular folder without creating virtual directory or an application in IIS, I registered the routes to my "folder/folder/mymvcappfolder/{controller}/{action}" and the default controller/action as well. However it workes fine if I pass at least the controller name in the Url otherwise it gives me **"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden"**.
I tried the below solutions in web.config but didn't worked out

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

And

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Any suggestions why my routes not working without passing the controller name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're pointing to a physical directory, it's not your route doesn't works with defaults,, it's the IIS what is blocking the access to this folder: ("The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory")...

To make this works you must enable route existing files in your RouteConfig:

```
RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Comment: But what if a simple index.html page works on the same directory?